# Gauge Chart has white segment appearing on iPhone

Tags: highcharts, gauge

I have implemented a gauge chart and overall it is working great. When testing on an iPhone it has a white "segment" appearing at the start of the animated line - this does not appear at a consistent time, and it does change in shape depending on how far through the animation is when appearing.

Wondering if anyone can confirm how to fix - I have tried everything I can to resolve.

[Screenshot of iPhone with Gauge loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLLaj.jpg)

Comment: Look like some kind of bug. Are you able to reproduce this behaviour on some online editor which I could test and work on? Or share a demo of your application?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel - thanks for your comment, but no sorry I don't have an online example - due to time constraints (and the fact my manager has an iphone so needed fixed) we have manually coded an SVG for the gauge. http://jsfiddle.net/2xhmmh5n/ is the code I originally based my implementation on.

Comment: I am afraid that I am not able to see this issue on the demo which you have shared. If you still need help please reproduce this behaviour or share an URL to your website